# Why does "Monitor of Built-in Analog Audio" Has no Sound?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I currently have a Let's Play Channel on Youtube, so, I need to record gameplay footage  (video and audio) along with microphone audio (in a separate file, with audacity).

I found a software called *Simple Screen Recorder (SSR)* to record gameplay video and audio footage, I have checked the website for instructions on how to adjust the things and the problems began.

First, the video is recorded just fine, it's the simplest software I could find to set up the configurations and get it up and running. **Problem is, no gameplay audio, no system audio**. Audacity records the microphone just well, so I started to take a look on the configurations on *PulseAudio Volume Control* while recording something with SSR. Many tutorials tell to change the audio imput to **Monitor of Built-in Analog Audio** in order to record the gameplay audio, but this did not work to me here.

I suspect that this *Monitor of Built-in Analog Audio* is not configured or that it does not have audio to be recorded at all, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know how far you got in this process, so I start from the beginning:

1. Install pavucontrol:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
   ```
2. Launch it:

   ```
   pavucontrol
   ```
3. On the **Input Devices** tab select **Show: All input devices**
4. Check the Volume level and if necessary **Unmute** the **Monitor of Built-in Analog Audio** channel by clicking on the little speaker icon.
5. Launch Audacity, start recording
6. While Audacity is recording: In the pavucontrol **Recording** tab change the Input Source for Audacity to **Monitor of Built-in Analog Audio**

Comment: Is pavucontrol necessary in order to enable "Monitor of ..." devices? Or is there a way to just enable it through the standard pulseaudio tools like `pacmd` or `pactl`?

Comment: Great, the steps number 3 and 4 helped me fixed the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks!

Comment: thank you very much, i've been googling everywhere and the problem is just this.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to do this through the command line. This uses the `pactl` command like CMCDragonkai requested.

1. Open a terminal and type `pactl set-source-mute alsa_output`
2. Press tab
3. Add `false` at the end and press enter
4. Continue with Audacity like in steps 5 and 6 of falconer's answer

On my machine, the command would be `pactl set-source-mute alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor false`. You might also need to adjust the volume like `pactl set-source-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor 100%`

Comment: Thanks mate, the monitors from my audio outputs had no sound but this fix my problem

Comment: Why `alsa_output`? Shouldn’t the mics be `alsa_input`?

Comment: Thank you! Audio worked for me, I could just not see it in pavucontrol (and OBS did not record), this fixed it for me!

Comment: @MPi the question asked about the "Monitor of <output>" not the input mics.

Answer (score 0):

My experience was with Audacity, had worked easily enough in previous Ubuntu versions.
I'm now using 10.14 LTS. I installed the pavucontrol, and soon got it working. Not without fiddling with a few things. See below

Make sure you go to Configuration in the pavucontrol tool. I had to select "Analog stereo ouput". Then go to Audacity and choose Pulse Pulse Video:0, in the main panel of Audacity. Then I was able to record. Thanks for this post!